No data shown using axio.get on the play store
I have an android app that has been accepted into the Google play store however after downloading it on my phone the data is not being shown. On the emulator and on a virtual device all works just fine.
For the app I am using react native.
I am using axio.get to retieve the text from a webpage. It's a page containing a text list, the intention being looping through the retrieved data and churning it out in a flatlist.
In the AndroidManifest the following has been declared:
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
I have also assigned this in the activity tag:
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
All to no avail.
If someone could shed any light on this issue, it would be highly appreciated.
Jon
